# Running ps shell command on Android programmatically

Tags: android, shell, ps

I'm trying to execute the ps command on my Android app, as such:

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    int read;
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.append(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    reader.close();

    // Waits for the command to finish.
    process.waitFor();
    Log.d(TAG, output.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {

} catch (InterruptedException e) {

}
```

I'm testing it on a Samsung Galaxy S6 with Lollipop. It runs, but all I see are root-owned processes.

On a Nexus 5 with Marshmallow though, I don't see root owned processes, but I see many other processes. It's still not a complete list.

Is there some kind of protection within Android that prevents me from seeing the full process list in certain devices/OS versions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, multiple mechanisms. On Linux, `ps` works through the `/proc` filesystem. Nougat (Android 7) is strictest so far, with [platform/system/core.git#c39ba5a](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/c39ba5ae32afb6329d42e61d2941d87ff66d92e3): you can't see any `/proc/PID` belong to other users at all.

> Enable hidepid=2 on /proc

> Add the following mount options to the /proc filesystem:

> ```
> hidepid=2,gid=3009
> ```

> This change blocks /proc access unless you're in group 3009
> (aka AID_READPROC).

`/proc` access is also restricted by various rules in [platform/system/sepolicy.git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy), some of which applies to earlier releases.

Comment: Thanks. Does the "top" command suffer from the same limitations as well? What I'm trying to achieve is looking for processes with the same package name as myself, but with a different UID, as well as looking for processes with the same UID as me, but with different package names. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @user1118764 Yes, `top` also uses the same filesystem interfaces for process information. I don't understand your goal though? All Android packages have unique package names, and each package has a unique UID (per user), unless two packages are signed with the same key *and* declare the same [`sharedUserId`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) in their manifests.

Comment: What you've described is normal Android behavior. However, there are some cases where this is not true. I'm trying to detect those cases.