# The android code executes the adb command and cannot obtain information about other processes

Tags: android, adb

I am doing car machine development, and I want to make a performance monitoring tool to test the performance of other car machine applications made by our company.

I try to use adb in my application to obtain other application process information; however, I found that executing the adb command cannot obtain the process information of other applications.

For example:
 `The performance tool application I made, the package name is:  com.example.perftools I have written two test applications, the package names are:  com.example.memorytest and com.example.cputest`

I want to use the adb command in com.example.perftools to get the process information of com.example.memorytest and com.example.cputest

For example：

`
I want to get the process number through the package name

**Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps")**

But I found that the obtained data does not contain the process information of com.example.memorytest and com.example.cputest

I tried using other adb commands：

**Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1")**

Also does not include process information for com.example.memorytest and com.example.cputest；

**Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1 -p ")**

There is still no process information for the pid

`

I tried a lot of adb commands, but I found that when I execute it in the code, I can't get the information of other processes,

I need help

I hope that executing adb in the code can only get information about other processes, such as cpu, etc.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)` just executes processes, this has nothing to to with `adb`! Especially as commands executed within `adb shell` are executed using a different user account and thus has different permissions. Since a few Android versions (not sure 10 or 11) apps can not query any information about other apps - thy simply don't see other apps in `ps` or `top`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43509440/150978 - Conclusion: What you are trying to do is not possible since Android 7.

Comment: @Robert   I put my app UID as android.uid.system `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"`. I tried doing `dumpsys meminfo <pid>` in the code。Can get information about other processes。but execute `top -n 1` or `top -n 1 -p <pid>` Unable to get other process information。Why is it possible to obtain memory information, but not to obtain cpu information?